# How to show the place of origin place of the images via openCV image stitching function?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

Such as there are three images called **(1st,2nd,3rd)** and after image stitching I get a completed photo which consists in the order of **(1st 3rd 2nd)**. Then I wonder how to get this order **(1st 3rd 2nd)**?

(Maybe they are in the same size such as 400*300 and I wonder if **OpenCV** could do that cause I'm going to process hundreds of images and I couldn't recognize these **hundreds** of images one by one using my eyes)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the order (and some other infos) of the stitched images with `cv.detail.matchesGraphAsString` [-> docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d74/group__stitching__rotation.html#gabaeb9dab170ea8066ae2583bf3a669e9)

```
graph matches_graph{
"weir_1.jpg" -- "weir_2.jpg"[label="Nm=157, Ni=135, C=2.45009"];
"weir_2.jpg" -- "weir_3.jpg"[label="Nm=89, Ni=70, C=2.01729"];
"weir_noise.jpg";
}
```

[image]

See more info [here](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md) using the [stitching package](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching)